# Prove that $f(r) \geq 0$ for $r \in (0,1]$

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, analysis, inequality

> Let $m$ be an arbitrary positive integer. I want to prove that 
>   $$
> f(r) = 1 - (1 + r)^{-m} + (1 + r^{-1})^{-m} - r
> $$
>   satisfies $f(r) \geq 0$ for $r \in (0,1]$.

### My notes on the problem:

It might be useful to rewrite the function as
$$
f(r) = \frac{r^m - \left(\frac{r}{1+r}\right)^m + \left(\frac{r^2}{1+r}\right)^m - r^{m+1}}{r^m} \implies\\
f(r) = \frac{[r(1+r)]^m - r^m + r^{2m} - r[r(1 + r)]^m}{[r(1+r)]^m}
$$
and show that the numerator is positive on the interval; haven't tried it yet.

It is notable that $f(1) = \lim_{r \to 0^+}f(r) = 0$.  I've tried taking the first derivative and showing that the function achieves a maximum within the interval, but wasn't able to make heads or tails of the derivative.

I also tried to show that $f''(r) < 0$ on the interval, again, to no avail.

I don't see how to use the AM-GM inequality here, or any similar tricks.

Comment: This came out in the process of trying problem VIII.6.1 from Bhatia's Matrix Analysis.  I'll post the full question should this turn out to be a dead-end.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$f(r) = 1-r -\dfrac{1-r^m}{(1+r)^m}=(1-r)\left(1-\dfrac{1}{(1+r)^m}-\dfrac{r^2}{(1+r)^m}-\cdots-\dfrac{r^{m-1}}{(1+r)^m}\right)>0 \iff (1+r)^m > 1+r+r^2+\cdots +r^{m-1}$ which is quite clear by simply expanding binomially the left side or by induction on $m$.

Comment: Oh my... this came out of simplifying a geometric series too, which may mean that I made it more confusing by condensing the problem.  I'll have to go back through my notes.

Comment: Thank you very much for the answer!  I'm a little miffed that I didn't catch it myself.

Comment: You are welcome !, Always look out for geometric series first..